# Cannot get past syntax error

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, calculated-column, error, calculated-column-formula

My coworker has written this code but continues to get a syntax error. We've checked field names and all are correctly spelled.

Any ideas what else could be wrong?

```
=IF(ISBLANK([Start Date]),"",IF(ISBLANK([End Date]),"",IF([Work Schedule]="Part-Time",NETWORKDAYS([Start Date],[End Date])*(4),IF([Work Schedule]="Full-Time",NETWORKDAYS([Start Date],[End Date])*(8),""))))
```

Comment: Are you trying to create a SharePoint calculated column or are you writing this formula inside excel file?

Answer (score 1):

`NETWORKDAYS()` function is not supported in SharePoint calculated formulas.

You have to use the formula like:

```
=IF(ISBLANK([Start Date]),"",IF(ISBLANK([End Date]),"",IF([Work Schedule]="Part-Time",DATEDIF([Start Date],[End Date],"d")*4,IF([Work Schedule]="Full-Time",DATEDIF([Start Date],[End Date],"d")*8,""))))
```

---

**Note**:

1. Sometimes comma(`,`) does not work in formula (it is based on language or regional settings on your site). So in that case use semicolon(`;`) instead of comma(`,`).
2. Use correct *display name* of your SharePoint columns in above formula.
3. Wrap column names inside `[]` if your column name has space in it. For example: `[My Column Name]`.

Comment: If you get the `#NUM` error change the position of start date and end date inside `DATEDIF()` like: `DATEDIF([End Date],[Start Date],"d")`.